# Zeckendorf to F(4k+2) representation

Tags: code-golf, math, fibonacci

### Background

Fibonacci numbers are defined as follows:

$$
F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1, F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}
$$

The **Zeckendorf representation** is a representation of positive integers as a sum of one or more non-adjacent Fibonacci numbers, using indices 2 and higher. It is known that such a representation is unique for every positive integer ([Zeckendorf's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem)), and it can be written as a positional base system using digits 0 and 1. For example:

$$
65 = 55 + 8 + 2 = F_{10} + F_{6} + F_{3} = \overline{100010010}_F
$$

The **\$F_{4k+2}\$ representation** is a similar representation but using every fourth Fibonacci number only, and with digits of at most 9. Some examples:

$$
\begin{align}
7 &= 7F_2 = \overline{7}_{F_{4k+2}} \\
8 &= 8F_2 = \overline{8}_{F_{4k+2}} \\
&= F_6 = \overline{10}_{F_{4k+2}} \\
65 &= F_{10} + F_6 + 2F_2 = \overline{112}_{F_{4k+2}} \\
\end{align}
$$

Note that this representation is not unique in general.

I invented this to multiply two numbers in Zeckendorf representation in subquadratic time, from the fact that the product of two \$F_{4k+2}\$s can be expanded to a sum of \$F_{4k+2}\$s:

$$
\begin{align} F_2 F_n &= F_n \\ F_6 F_n &= F_{n-4} + F_n + F_{n+4} \\
F_{10} F_n &= F_{n-8} + F_{n-4} + F_n + F_{n+4} + F_{n+8} \\ &\cdots \\
F_{4k+2} F_n &= \sum_{i=-k}^{k} F_{n+4i}
\end{align}
$$

### Task

Given a positive integer in Zeckendorf representation, output the same number in \$F_{4k+2}\$ representation. If there are multiple possible representations, output any of them.

Both the input and output may be represented using a list or string of digits, in the order of increasing or decreasing positional value. For example, if the given number is `11`, you may choose to take e.g. `"10100"`, `"00101"`, `[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]`, or `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]` as input, and give `"13"`, `"31"`, `[1, 3]`, or `[3, 1]` as output.

### Test cases

```
Number Zeckendorf      F4k+2 (not showing all possible answers)
7      1010            7
10     10010           12
12     10101           14
51     10100101        63
144    10000000000     242
233    100000000000    415
490    1001001000100   1203 or 1172 or 862
986    10101010101010  2414
```

Comment: Can I take as input the indices in the input which are 1?

Comment: Some equalities which might be useful: \$3 F_{4k+3} = 5 F_{4k+2} - F_{4(k-1)+2}\$, \$3 F_{4k+1} = 2 F_{4k+2} - F_{4(k-1)+2}\$, \$3 F_{4k} = F_{4k+2} + F_{4(k-1)+2}\$.

Comment: @CommandMaster No.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 88 bytes

Expects a binary array in reverse order. Returns an array which may include leading 0's.

```javascript
a=>a.reduce((q,c,i)=>(t+=c*=x=y+(y=x),i&3?q:[x,...q]),[],t=y=0,x=1).map(x=>t/(t%=x,x)|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFRT8IwEMff@RQXEk1Palm7wUBy88lXv8CyhzqKYgaDbZAS9bPPFgYqXntp0/vd3T/Xd73XdV4tN839upybdkGtpkSLysx3uWFsy3O@REpYM6D8jiwdBuxAFvnyNnzcPqSWCyG2GfI04w0dKOCWJIqV3jBLSTNkzQ1ZbvEzwHaW9gD6MpBBn8MvGw6Bxegu8Sl@Dfi4DBwg1bmA/A8oD0Rn4C/jgZF0wDjsWpytY44VoghBReqK6BBPqDBEiOToItNv70fEE9HU6ZQqCKGsQMpY@XMy/tF9Wf0uYzoZ@65OedYTi7J60vkbq4ES@HBJhWlAA0Hqplxnx7E@71YvpkL3Q3tT1YbhzHF5ua7LwoiifGULptE9fmH7DQ)

#### How?

We have two steps:

1. During the `reduce()` step, we convert the input array \$a[\:]\$ of length \$L\$ into an integer \$t\$ by computing Fibonacci numbers \$F_2\$ to \$F_{L+1}\$ and adding those for which the corresponding entry in \$a[\:]\$ is set. At the same time, we store the Fibonacci numbers of the form \$F_{4k+2}\$ in this range in an array \$q[\:]\$, from highest to lowest.
2. During the `map()` step, we convert \$q[\:]\$ into the final output by computing \$\lfloor t/x\rfloor\$ for each entry \$x\$ and reducing \$t\$ modulo \$x\$ after each iteration.

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                     // a[] = input array
a.reduce((q, c, i) =>    // for each value c at index i in a[],
  (                      // using q[] as the accumulator:
    t +=                 //   add to t ...
      c *=               //     c multiplied by ...
        x = y + (y = x), //       the next Fibonacci number x
    i & 3 ?              //   if i is not a multiple of 4:
      q                  //     leave q[] unchanged
    :                    //   else:
      [x, ...q]          //     append x at the beginning of q[]
  ),                     //
  [],                    //   start with q = []
  t = y = 0,             //   start with t = 0, y = 0
  x = 1                  //   start with x = 1
)                        // end of reduce()
.map(x =>                // for each value x in q[]:
  t / (t %= x, x)        //   return floor(t / x)
  | 0                    //   and reduce t modulo x
)                        // end of map()
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
ƶ+ÅfODÅF4ι2èRvy‰`s?
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//2Dbtw61p/i6HW91Mzu00OrwiqKzyUcOGhGL7//@jDXQUgMgQQsYCAA), or [try all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@koGunoGRfGRzk8v/YNu3DrWn@Lodb3UzO7TQ6vCKorPJRw4aEYvv/tYe22f@PVjI0MDRQ0lEA0nAGEMIYCDYcoHERmkEIhOGGwKFSLAA)

-2 thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen

Takes the input as a reversed list. Turns the number from Zeckendorf representation to an integer, and then finds an \$F_{4k+2}\$ representation greedily.

### Explanation

```
ƶ      multiply each number by its 1-based index
+      and add that to the original list, so effectively we multiplied by the 2-based index
Åf     get the n-th Fibonacci number, for each N in that list
O      and sum, let's call it V
D      duplicate
ÅF     list the fibonacci numbers less than or equal to it
4ι     uninterleave to four lists [a[0::4], a[1::4], a[2::4], a[3::4]]
2è     and take the third element, a[2::4]
R      reverse that list
v      and for each element in the list:
 y      push it
 ‰      calculate divmod(V, element)
 `      dump (division, mod)  to the stack
 s      swap, to get (mod, division)
 ?      and print the result of the division without a newline, leaving the modulo in the stack in place of V.
```

Comment: `ʒN4%<}` can be `4ι2è` to save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 41 bytes

```
Ｆθ⊞υ∨¬υΣ…⮌υ²≔ΣＥ⮌θ×Ｉι§υκθＦ⮌Φυ¬﹪κ⁴«Ｉ÷θι≧﹪ιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5dC4IwFIav9Vfs8ggLLLrrSozAC0usPyC68uB0uQ8pot@@NkUa28U4z3uet24rWYuKW3sXksAYkcKoFgwlFwlnocFElFxND@m75ixtxRNKNjGp2DzZRe4cwkQpfAzgubz6E6MjbtgzBWmlNKD7JjobGvbygs5nKRldfnavqRNyzaQnvD8XjeECOkr2no/IJwwKiYNedmaDPuKEjZNRgnOZwFVYCpX4aNcNbrq4vtZu43i5/tnNxH8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆθ⊞υ∨¬υΣ…⮌υ²
```

Generate `F(2)...F(n+1)` where `n` is the number of bits in the input.

```
≔ΣＥ⮌θ×Ｉι§υκθ
```

Convert the input from Zeckendorf to integer.

```
Ｆ⮌Φυ¬﹪κ⁴«Ｉ÷θι≧﹪ιθ
```

Greedily convert the input from integer to `F(4k+2)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 150 bytes

```python
def f(i):
 a=b=g=1;o=0
 def n(o):
  while(z:=(o+g-1)//8&g):o-=o//8%2-(z*145>>4)
  return o
 while i:o=n(o+i%2*b);a,b=b,n(a+b);i//=2;g=16*g+1
 return o
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XU9JboQwELz7Fb5MZLMEtzEMA_LkKREoLJaQjQijJPOQXHLhkrwol_lNzBJE0ral7ip3dfXHV_c2NEaP4-dlqPzk9v5UVrgiiqYI57KQtYTMSIbwhGtiJhy_NKotyTWVxLi1DzQIkruapsaXxqYH7pOrAyI6nwW1v_tyuPQaG7T0YZUaaZVcdeBOQbPcK2ThaZK7tlBBIHlmh8ZO7QLaeld3D5XpcYuVRbpSEza5efSUZ2R7_9y1aiB2YNcrPRDlNeUrsZvMOaeUeoYuMuPt-4jnAAYM7-KI1hrYXwY4Ar61wJ4RKIKN2ZNxiECIVe03ZoYLjngY_qNmTkCExIltHqY7vdkDC9EpiTcX25kUQSzL_QA)

Expects binary coded Zeckendorf and returns hex coded F4k+2.

### How?

Uses the identity \$7F_n=
F_{n-4}+F_{n+4}\$ to express addition in F4k+2 using "two-sided carry".